# How to draw a Polyline on google map from other window

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I'm trying to draw a Polyline on my map.  The script that draws the Polyline is defined and called from a pop-up window.

```
        var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
             map: window.parent.map,
             path: result.routeCoordinates,
             geodesic: true,
             strokeColor: '#00FF00',
             strokeOpacity: 1.0,
             strokeWeight: 2
         });
```

"map" is defined as a global variable and when I'm debugging I actually see that the contents of window.parent.map are correct.

Still this approach gives me the following error:
**InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map**

I found other threads about this error but I din't manage to solve my problem based on these.

UPDATE: Here some code that will allow to reproduce the error.
First the main page containing the map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />

    <title>GMaps</title>
    <!-- Google Maps API v3 -->
    <script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
    </script>

    <script>
    // Global variable 
    var map, infowindow;

        function initialize(){
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.924717, 18.423328), 
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };


            map = new google.maps.Map(
                      document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                      mapOptions);
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position : new google.maps.LatLng(-33.924717, 18.423328), icon: '/img/empty_small.png'});

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
               var htmlcontent = '<div class="popup"><iframe src="example2.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" class="popop">iFrames required</iframe></div>';
               infoWindow.setContent(htmlcontent);
               infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });       

        }
        </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
    <div id = "map-canvas">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Secondly the popup window (called example2.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />

    <title>GMaps</title>
    <!-- Google Maps API v3 -->
    <script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
    </script>

    <script>
    function drawPolyline() {
        var coordinates = [
          {lat: -33.924717, lng: 18.423328},
          {lat: -33.924717, lng: 20.458451},
        ];
        var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
             map: window.parent.map,
             path: coordinates,
             geodesic: true,
             strokeColor: '#00FF00',
             strokeOpacity: 1.0,
             strokeWeight: 2
         });
      }
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="drawPolyline();return false;">Draw Polyline</a>
</body>
</html>
```

For completeness, relevant tags in the stylesheet are the following:

```
html{height: 100%}
body{height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
#map-canvas{height: 100%}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I edited the post. Thanks for pointing me to the MCVE page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to load Maps JavaScript API twice. I would suggest removing the load of Maps JavaScript API from your popup page and using window.parent.google.maps.Polyline in your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />

        <title>GMaps</title>

       <script>
           function drawPolyline() {
               var coordinates = [
                   {lat: -33.924717, lng: 18.423328},
                   {lat: -33.924717, lng: 20.458451},
               ];
               var route = new window.parent.google.maps.Polyline({
                   map: window.parent.map,
                   path: coordinates,
                   geodesic: true,
                   strokeColor: '#00FF00',
                   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                   strokeWeight: 2
               });
           }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="drawPolyline();return false;">Draw Polyline</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This approach worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, solved my issue.  I wanted to upvote but unfortunately I haven't got enough reputation.